# How to integrate Taurus with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, taurus

I created a yaml file and I would like to run Taurus test using Jenkinsfile.
I tried with these :

```
stage("run test") {
    bzt "stepping.yml"
}
```

But i am receiving an error regarding bzt.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you show an error message

BTW, You can also check these to guide you to integrate Jenkins with Taurus

- https://gettaurus.org/kb/Jenkins/
- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-test-through-jenkins-pipelines